# How to work with a single instance of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I am attempting to apply several different animations to a single class ".box". Currently in my code I have a single animation and I'm going to add more and create an array that applies my animations in order, but with my current code I'm not sure how to apply each animation to each instance of the ".box" class without making something like ".box 1, .box 2, .box 3" and then looping through. If I'm completely wrong in my thinking please let me know, but I feel there is a way to do this. Here is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Css Animation Practice</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


</head>
<style>

html,body { height: 100%; width:100%;}

body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


div{
}

.container{
    text-align: center;
}

#danceButton{
    position:relative;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}

.boxBorder{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    margin:10px;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    border:3px solid black;
}

.box{
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin:75px;
}   

.clearDiv{
    clear:both;
}

.rotate{
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100%{
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}



</style>


<body>


<button id="danceButton" onclick="danceFunction()" value="danceButton">Dance!</button>

<div class="clearDiv"></div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

</div>



<script>

var clicked = 0;

    function danceFunction(){

        if(clicked == 0){
                $(".box").addClass("rotate");
                clicked = 1
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".box").removeClass("rotate");
                    clicked = 0;
                }, 2000)    
            }
    }


</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[eq()][1]`. For example, to target the first element that has the clas `.box` you can do this:

```
$(".box").eq(0); // $(".box") gives you a zero based array so the first element is at index 0
```

Or to target the second:

```
$(".box").eq(1);
```

You can also use this syntax:

```
$(".box:eq(1)")
```

Here is a working example and a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0LwgbyL/):

```js
$(function () { // shorthand "on dom ready" function
    $('#danceButton').click(function () {
        var num = $('#boxNumber').val();
        var $box = $(".box").eq(num);
        $box.addClass("rotate");
        clicked = 1
        setTimeout(function () {
            $box.removeClass("rotate");
            clicked = 0;
        }, 2000)
    });
});
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
div {
}
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
#danceButton {
    position:relative;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
}
.boxBorder {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#d8d8d8;
    margin:10px;
    height: 200px;
    width:200px;
    border:3px solid black;
}
.box {
    position:relative;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin:75px;
}
.clearDiv {
    clear:both;
}
.rotate {
    -webkit-animation: rotation 2s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select a box number to work with
<select name="" id="boxNumber">
    <option value="0" selected>1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
    <option value="4">5</option>
    <option value="5">6</option>
    <option value="6">7</option>
    <option value="7">8</option>
</select><br>
<button id="danceButton" value="danceButton">Dance!</button>
<div class="clearDiv"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxBorder">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna have to loop, but you could make it easy. For example, if you store your animations as a simple array `["rotate", "rotate", "jump", ...]` with classes corresponding to the boxes, then you could use `$().each` function, like

```
$(".box").each(funcion(index) {
    var box = $(this)
    box.addClass( animations[index] )
    ...
      box.removeClass ...
    ...
})
```

Comment: That's precisely the issue. I am using a single button to apply multiple animations to different instances of the same object. I wasn't aware of the $().each function, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'll post finished code with the animations. Thank you for your quick responses both of you.

Comment: So here's the finished example guys. Unfortunately it's not actually working in JSFiddle. I'm sure I did something wrong, but it works great on my end. If you know why it's not working in JSFiddle that'd be a great help for the future. http://jsfiddle.net/9h499pvj/

Comment: I apologize, I've figured out why JSFiddle didn't work. I needed to set the Frameworks & Extensions to no <wrap> in head Thank you for helping me solve this problem.